# C# create custom dialog result form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a two forms in C#, one I intend to use as a dialog result and the other is the "main" form. how do I set up the other form so that the code in form1 waits until the second form is dismissed before resuming executing the next line of code?

Comment: The Form.ShowDialog() method is a remarkably poorly known method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Form.ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method on form2.

```
// Some code in form1
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
// Note: this code will resume after form2 has been closed.
```

Alternatively, you can subscribe to the [Form.Closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event to run some code when form2 closes.

```
// Some code in form1
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Closed += (s, e) {
    // Note: this code will run after form2 has been closed.
};
form2.Show();
```

Comment: When using `ShowDialog` you should wrap the Form objects in a using statement as the forms are disposable.

Answer (score 0):

The code might look like this:

```
...

var o = new Form2();
o.ShowDialog();

// resumes after closure of Form2
...
```

The other thing you can do here is:

```
var res = o.ShowDialog();
if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    // do something because the user canceled the dialog
}
```

Further, you can set default **Accept** and **Cancel** buttons on the form. Just go to the properties of the `Form` and take note to the [`CancelButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) and [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx). That does two things:

1. Determines the `DialogResult` sent by those buttons.
2. Manages the <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key strokes for those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method:

```
if (MyForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Resume after closure on "OK"
}
else
{
    // Resume after closure on "Cancel/Abort/No/None/Etc..."
}
```